# How can I call functions from module patterns from an event function

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events, module-pattern

I am experimenting with the Javascript module pattern and the html5 canvas by making a simple html5 based game and have run into my first obstacle. I am listening for a mousemove event over a canvas.

```
init: function () {
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    gameCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.redrawAvatar);
}
```

What I'm doing is letting my avatar follow the movement of the mousepointer over the canvas.

The problem then is that I have several functions in my module which I wish to call from inside the `redrawAvatar` function, like so:

```
redrawAvatar: function (mouseEvent) {
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"),
    avatarCoord = {x: mouseEvent.offsetX, y: mouseEvent.offsetY},
    enemyCoord = {x: 100, y: 100};

    this.clear(gameCanvas);
    this.drawAvatar(avatarCoord);
    this.drawEnemy(enemyCoord);

    if (that.isCollision({coord: avatarCoord, size: 30}, {coord: enemyCoord, size: 30})) {
       alert("Avatar died, collided with enemy");
    }
}
```

While inside `redrawAvatar` the this object is not my module anymore but is instead the source of the event (the canvas in this case).

Here is the essence of my module:

```
var MyGame = (function () {

    var Game = {

        draw: function (image, coord) {},

        drawAvatar: function (coord) {},

        clear: function (canvas) { canvas.width = canvas.width + 1 - 1;},

        drawEnemy: function (xPos, yPos) {},

        isCollision: function (a, b) {},

        redrawAvatar: function (mouseEvent) {
            var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"),
                avatarCoord = {x: mouseEvent.offsetX, y: mouseEvent.offsetY},
                enemyCoord = {x: 100, y: 100};

            this.clear(gameCanvas);
            this.drawAvatar(avatarCoord);
            this.drawEnemy(enemyCoord);
            if (that.isCollision({coord: avatarCoord, size: 30}, {coord: enemyCoord, size: 30})) {
                alert("Avatar died, collided with enemy");
            }
        },

        init: function () {
            var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
            gameCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.redrawAvatar);
        }
    };

    (function () {
        var that = Game;
        that.init();
    }());

}());
```

How do I get to the functions in my module which I would like to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to use the current context (in your case the game module) in the function as opposed to the event's context.

```
gameCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.redrawAvatar.bind(this));
```

Here is a basic demo reproducing the binding effect. It uses a click event.

```js
var MyGame = (function () {
        var Game = {
            scoped: 5,
            redrawAvatar: function (mouseEvent) {
             alert(this.scoped);
            },

            init: function () {
                var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("d");
                gameCanvas.addEventListener("click", this.redrawAvatar.bind(this));
            }
        };
        (function () {
            var that = Game;
            that.init();
        }());
    }());
```

```html
<div id="d">Basic element for click handler (click for demo)</div>
```

Run code snippet or ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/9szhbcyu/)***